# In Java how would I combine a grid of buttons with a grid of integers to create a minesweeper board?

Tags: java

So far all I have managed to do is combine my two files into one file that creates a GUI with the grid of buttons and runs an instance of minesweeper separately. I need the values from the grid of integers to reflect onto the grid of buttons so that after I click a button it reveals the integer underneath. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Minesweeper extends JFrame implements MouseListener
{
private JButton [][] gridz;
private int [][] g;
private int max;

public Minesweeper()
{
    gridz= new JButton [10][10];
    builder();
    g=new int[10][10];
    setRandom(10);
}

public void setRandom(int max)
{
    int z=0;
    while(z<max)
    {
        int r=(int)(Math.random()*g.length);
        int c=(int)(Math.random()*g[r].length);
        if(g[r][c]==0)
        {
            g[r][c]=-1;
            z++;
        }
    }
}

public int count(int r, int c)
{
    int x=0;

    if((r-1)>=0 && (c-1)>=0 && (r-1)<g.length && (c-1)<g.length && g[r-1][c-1]==-1)
    {
        x++;
    }
    if((r-1)>=0 && (r-1)<g.length && g[r-1][c]==-1)
    {
        x++;
    }
    if((r-1)>=0 && (c+1)>=0 && (r-1)<g.length && (c+1)<g.length && g[r-1][c+1]==-1)
    {
        x++;
    }
    if((c-1)>=0 && (c-1)<g.length && g[r][c-1]==-1)
    {
        x++;
    }
    if((c+1)>=0 && (c+1)<g.length && g[r][c+1]==-1)
    {
        x++;
    }
    if((r+1)>=0 && (c-1)>=0 && (r+1)<g.length && (c-1)<g.length && g[r+1][c-1]==-1)
    {
        x++;
    }
    if((r+1)>=0 && (r+1)<g.length && g[r+1][c]==-1)
    {
        x++;
    }
    if((r+1)>=0 && (c+1)>=0 && (r+1)<g.length && (c+1)<g.length && g[r+1][c+1]==-1)
    {
        x++;
    }
    return x;

}

public void setCounts()
{
    for(int r=0; r<g.length; r++)
    {
        for(int c=0; c<g[r].length; c++)
        {
            if(g[r][c]==0)
            {
                g[r][c]=count(r,c);
            }
        String formatted = String.format("%2d", g[r][c]);
        System.out.print(formatted + " ");
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
}

public void builder()
{
    setSize(500,500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
    for(int r=0; r<gridz.length; r++)
    {
        for(int c=0; c<gridz[r].length; c++)
        {
            gridz[r][c]=new JButton("*");
            gridz[r][c].setActionCommand(r+":"+c);
            gridz[r][c].addMouseListener(this);
            getContentPane().add(gridz[r][c]);
        }
    }
    setVisible(true);
}



public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
    Component c = e.getComponent();
    JButton b = (JButton)c;
    System.out.println(b.getActionCommand());
    String s=b.getActionCommand();
    int f=s.indexOf(':');
    if(f>=0)
    {
        String row=s.substring(0, f);
        String col=s.substring(f+1);
        String text=row+ '!' +col;
        b.setText(text);
    }
}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
{   
}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
{
}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
{
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Minesweeper a = new Minesweeper();
    a.setCounts();
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "BOOM");
}
```

}

Comment: Take a look at the `MinesweeperPanel` class in my [Minesweeper project](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/minesweeper) to see one way to combine `JButtons` and an integer display.  @MadProgrammer's answer and advice is also excellent.

Answer (score 2):

One of the (many) things you want to do, is decouple your code.  This means that the "logic" for the "game" should be independent of the "view", meaning that you can easily change the logic without adversely effecting the view.

This is where things like [model-view-controller](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mvc-design-pattern/) and [single responsibility](https://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html) concepts come into play.

What you should (try) and do is start by describing the "data" or "model".  What properties does it have and what functionality can be executed by other parties.

Since the models state could change, independently, you'll also need some way to notify interested parties, this is where an [observer](https://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) is helpful.

For example, a model for the game might be represented like...

```
public interface MineSweeperModel {
    public interface Observer {
        public void cellValueDidChange(MineSweeperModel model, int col, int row, int value);
    }
    public int getRows();
    public int getColumns();
    public int getValueAt(int col, int row);
    public void expose(int col, int row);
    public void setObserver(Observer observer);
}
```

Now, that's cool and everything, but what we need is some kind of implementation, which might look something like...

```
public class DefaultMineSweeperModel implements MineSweeperModel {

    private int rows;
    private int cols;

    private int[][] bombsMap;
    private int[][] visibleState;

    private Observer observer;

    public DefaultMineSweeperModel(int rows, int cols, int maxBombs) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;

        bombsMap = new int[cols][rows];
        visibleState = new int[cols][rows];

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int count = 0;
        while (count < maxBombs) {
            int row = rnd.nextInt(rows);
            int col = rnd.nextInt(cols);
            if (bombsMap[col][row] == 0) {
                bombsMap[col][row] = -1;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setObserver(Observer observer) {
        this.observer = observer;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumns() {
        return cols;
    }

    @Override
    public int getValueAt(int col, int row) {
        return visibleState[col][row];
    }

    @Override
    public void expose(int col, int row) {
        if (visibleState[col][row] == 0 && bombsMap[col][row] == -1) {
            // You've found a mine, might want to do something about it...
            visibleState[col][row] = -1;
            fireCellValueDidChange(col, row, -1);
        } else if (visibleState[col][row] == 0) {
            // Empty cell
            visibleState[col][row] = 1;
            fireCellValueDidChange(col, row, 1);
        }
    }

    protected void fireCellValueDidChange(int col, int row, int value) {
        if (observer == null) {
            return;
        }
        observer.cellValueDidChange(this, col, row, value);
    }

}
```

Now, we could just as easily create a "easy", "hard" and "you're going to die" implementations and seed the properties internally, but this basic implementation provides us with enough capacity to configure it.

But why (use a `interface`)?  One of the principles of OO is "information hiding", which is supported by the concept of [Polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

This means we can create any kind of model, with any kind of internal logic, but any one wanting to make use of the model, can easily do so by simply accepting a instance of the `interface`.

Now, the UI.  This is basically responsible for providing a visual representation of the state of the model.

```
public class MineSweeperPane extends JPanel {

    private JButton[] buttons;
    private MineSweeperModel model;

    public MineSweeperPane(MineSweeperModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        model.setObserver(new MineSweeperModel.Observer() {
            @Override
            public void cellValueDidChange(MineSweeperModel model, int col, int row, int value) {
                int index = (model.getRows() * row) + col;
                if (index >= buttons.length) {
                    System.err.println("No view for cell @ " + col + "x" + row);
                    return;
                }
                buttons[index].setText(Integer.toString(value));
            }
        });

        // You should be using ActionListener
        MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                JComponent source = (JComponent) e.getComponent();
                // Here's something they won't teach you...
                GridBagConstraints gbc = ((GridBagLayout)getLayout()).getConstraints(source);
                System.out.println(gbc.gridx + "x" + gbc.gridy);
                
                // Use class based Integer so we don't get NullPointerException
                Integer row = (Integer)source.getClientProperty("row");
                Integer col = (Integer)source.getClientProperty("col");
                if (row == null || col == null) {
                    System.err.println("!! Invalid cell");
                    return;
                }
                
                System.out.println("Clicked " + col + "x" + row);
                getModel().expose(col, row);
            }
        };

        int rowCount = model.getRows();
        int colCount = model.getColumns();

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        buttons = new JButton[rowCount * colCount];
        for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < colCount; col++) {
                JButton btn = makeButton(col, row, model);
                btn.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
                
                gbc.gridx = col;
                gbc.gridy = row;
                add(btn, gbc);

                buttons[row * rowCount + col] = btn;
            }
        }
    }

    public MineSweeperModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    protected JButton makeButton(int col, int row, MineSweeperModel model) {
        JButton btn = new JButton(Integer.toString(model.getValueAt(col, row))) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(35, 35);
            }
        };
        btn.setFocusable(false);
        btn.setFocusPainted(false);
        btn.putClientProperty("row", row);
        btn.putClientProperty("col", col);
        return btn;
    }
}
```

You will note two things.

1. I use `get`/`setClientProperty` to get and set the cell coordinates for the button within the model.  This allows me to seed the `int` values without needing to format/parse them to/from a `String`, which is, frankly, messy
2. I also cheated and demonstrated the ability to pull the buttons grid coordinates directly from the `GridBagLayout` itself.  I prefer to the first, but this is a nice side effect not many people know or make use of it.

When "clicked" (and you should be using an `ActionListener`, but you're apparently not meant to be using an `ActionListener` because you've not learnt about them ... which begs the question of, why are you using a `JButton` when `ActionListener` is the primary mechanism for monitoring for when it's triggered ), the UI updates the model.  If there are any changes to the model, the model's observer is notified, which then allows the UI to update its visual state.

I've not put any logic in to the model, apart from exposing the underlying value of the cell (difference between the `visialMap` and `bombMap`), so you'll need to do that

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to achieve this. You could simply include a line in your builder method that matches a button to a value from the `g` array and stores it in a hashmap or some other data structure like so `mineHashMap.put(gridz[r][c], g[r][c]);`, this way we can check the hashmap later in the mouse event method to find the correct value from the hashmap like so:

```
int value = mineHashMap.get(b);
b.setText(value+"");`
```

If starting from scratch, then a quick and easy/dirty solution would be to extend the JButton class to create a `customJBotton` which would store the integer value inside the class when you create the custom button, and you could contain other logic in it too. Then later when the button is clicked you can easily get the number in the mouse event like so `b.setText(b.getMineValue());` or call a custom method you created in the custom button like so `b.revealMine();` which would effectively do `this.setText(mineValue);`

There are many many other ways to do this, but the two options above would slot into your code quite easily. Custom painting on a JPanel rather than using buttons would also be a smart option but it does require more technical understanding and code.